# ¿Cuál es la función de un Channel en Go?

Tags: go

No me acaba de quedar claro, ¿cuál es la función y la finalidad de un channel en `Go`? y lo que he encontrado en la página es este ejemplo, pero sigo sin comprenderlo.

```
// _Channels_ are the pipes that connect concurrent
// goroutines. You can send values into channels from one
// goroutine and receive those values into another
// goroutine.

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    // Create a new channel with `make(chan val-type)`.
    // Channels are typed by the values they convey.
    messages := make(chan string)

    // _Send_ a value into a channel using the `channel <-`
    // syntax. Here we send `"ping"`  to the `messages`
    // channel we made above, from a new goroutine.
    go func() { messages <- "ping" }()

    // The `<-channel` syntax _receives_ a value from the
    // channel. Here we'll receive the `"ping"` message
    // we sent above and print it out.
    msg := <-messages
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para hablar de `channels` tenemos que hablar de `goroutines`.

Una `goroutine` es muy parecido a lo que en otros lenguajes se conoce como `thread` o `hilo`. Es básicamente una tarea que se ejecuta de forma independiente de otras.

Existen más cosas a considerar pero para ponerlo simple, si queremos ejecutar una función como una `goroutine` sólo debemos anteponer la palabra `go` antes de la llamada de dicha función, así:

```
go function()
```

Ahora bien, para que las `goruotines` puedan comunicarse usamos los `channels` (esa es su verdadera función).

Un `channel` se puede declarar así:

```
count := make(chan int)
```

Ahora, cabe mencionar que hay dos tipos de `channels`, están los `Buffered channels` y los `Unbuffered channels`. Pongo un ejemplo de ambos:

```
// Unbuffered channel
count := make(chan int)
// Buffered channel
count:= make(chan int, 10)
```

Los `Buffered channels` tienen una capacidad máxima y si intentamos usarlos más de esas veces obtendremos un error.

La mayor diferencia sería que con los `Buffered channels` no se puede garantizar que los mensajes han sido entregados.

Para enviar un mensaje a un `channel` hacemos lo siguiente:

```
// Buffered channel
messages := make(chan string, 2)
// Enviar un mensaje a un channel.
messages <- "Golang"
```

Para recibir el mensaje del `channel` hacemos esto:

```
value := <-messages
```

Finalmente te dejo un ejemplo completo usando `channels` y `goroutines`, explico el código con comentarios dentro del mismo.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// wg se usa para esperar a que el programa termine.
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    count := make(chan int)
    // Esto es para saber cuánto esperar, se agrega 1 para cada goroutine.
    wg.Add(2)

    fmt.Println("Inician Goroutines")
    //Empieza una goroutine con la etiqueta "A"
    go printCounts("A", count)
    //Empieza una goroutine con la etiqueta "B"
    go printCounts("B", count)
    fmt.Println("Empieza el channel")
    count <- 1
    // Espera a que las goroutines terminen.
    fmt.Println("Esperando para finalizar")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("\nFinalizando el programa")
}

func printCounts(label string, count chan int) {
    // Vamos a ejecutar el Done cuando terminemos.
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        //Recibe un mensaje del Channel
        val, ok := <-count
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("Se ha cerrado el channel")
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("Contador: %d recibió desde %s \n", val, label)
        if val == 10 {
            fmt.Printf("El channel fue cerrado desde %s \n", label)
            // Cerrar el channel
            close(count)
            return
        }
        val++
        // Enviar de regreso el contador a la otra goroutine.
        count <- val
    }
}
```

La salida sería algo como esto:

```
Inician Goroutines
Empieza el channel
Contador: 1 recibió desde A
Contador: 2 recibió desde B
Esperando para finalizar
Contador: 3 recibió desde A
Contador: 4 recibió desde B
Contador: 5 recibió desde A
Contador: 6 recibió desde B
Contador: 7 recibió desde A
Contador: 8 recibió desde B
Contador: 9 recibió desde A
Contador: 10 recibió desde B
El channel fue cerrado desde B
Se ha cerrado el channel
Finalizando el programa
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando acá: [Ejemplo Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ArAWz9E3Ij)

Answer (score 1):

vi el mismo ejemplo que tu y tambien explican muy bien para que son los `channels`. Los `channels` son un "conducto" por el cual puedes enviar o recibir información. La flecha de la declaración es la que nos dice en que dirección "fluye" la información. Una de las particularidades de los `channels` es que al momento de enviar información espera a que el receptor de esta este listo y con la información recibida para seguir ejecutando para asi en el ejemplo especifico poder mostrarlo.

Declaras tu `channel` diciendole que recibira un tipo `string`

```
messages := make(chan string)
```

Envias información a tu `channel` y le envias el string "ping"

```
go func() { messages <- "ping" }()
```

Recibes la información de tu `channel` (en este caso "ping")

```
msg := <-messages
```

Finalmente imprimes el valor

```
fmt.Println(msg)
```

Comment: Mil gracias! Ahora lo tengo un poco más claro.

Comment: De nada! @BigHelmet yo tambien me pondre a estudiar sobre este tema jejeje